# RegexValidator.pregMatch for a unicode British pound symbol?

Tags: java, regex, preg-match

I am trying to find price in Java for a specific currency symbol on the page and it works for "$" sign just fine. But some pages have a unicode symbol for British pound (\u00a3). Like this for example:

```
\u00a3139.99
```

How can I accommodate match for the unicode pound symbol in the following example? Instead of $ I need to look for \u00a3 but it doesn't work...

```
match = RegexValidator.pregMatch("<td class=\"tdprice\">\\$([^<]+)</td>", tr);
```

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like an encoding problem.  \u00a3 is ANSI for `£`, not UNICODE. Are you sure you don't mean \u009c?

Comment: Are you talking about this symbol `£`? You can catch it using `\£` or `\\u00a3`

Comment: I tried `match = RegexValidator.pregMatch("<td class=\"tdprice\">\\u00a3([^<]+)</td>", tr);` but it doesn't work. Price is empty

Comment: Here is how the page code looks like for that price: `<td class=\"tdprice\">\u00a3139.99</td>`